# How can I configure Ubuntu Server to use Node.js for WebSockets, and Apache2 for everything else?

Tags: node.js, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have a very simple WebSocket Server built with Node.js and the WS package.

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss             = new WebSocketServer({
        port: 8080
    });

wss.on('connection', function(client) {

    client.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    client.send('something');
});


// Console will print the message
console.log('-=-=- Server running :8080 -=-=-');
```

When I try to connect using a dead-simple client, the connection times out.

```
<script>
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.75:8080');

    ws.onconnect = function(){
        console.log("Connected!");
    };


</script>
```

The server starts/runs without error, but the client always times out the connection. Do I need to configure iptables or apache to send the traffic on port 8080 to my node server that I wrote? I was thinking that the server would automatically start listening on port 8080. (I apologize in advance if this is an amature-ish question. I'm VERY new to Node.js)

Comment: Your server listens on 8080, your client connects to 1947...

Comment: that was a Typo actually. sorry about that. I tried changing ports and forgot to swap the client back for the question. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special regarding Apache so long as you don't have any Apache traffic serving on the same port. You will just have two separate servers running at the same time on separate ports and will have to direct your traffic accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried serving a simple webpage through node that isn't your websockets integration? I'm wondering if it could be that node is working correctly but there's a problem with the websockets.

Comment: When I first installed Node.js I set up a VERY simple webserver that just output "IT WORKS!" in a webpage. I used proxypass.. .OH SH*T! I still have my proxypass set up for port 8080! It forewards traffic on port 8080 to /node!

Comment: Now that I think about it, my source file is in /node. I use node myFirstApp.js inside of /node. But the client should still be able to connect straight to the webroot:8080 right?

Comment: Hey, I edited your question. As soon as it's accepted I'll accept your answer as correct. The truth is, you DON'T need to do anything with Apache to get this configuration up and running. :D

Comment: Hrmm yeah as long as you are in the correct directory and you absolute and relative paths are all correct there shouldn't be an issue, but since you have no problems starting the server I don't think the problem is with node if you CAN run a webpage that says "IT WORKS!" on the target 8080 port.

Comment: I would accept this answer if we could edit it to remove the last two paragraphs. Since, nowhere in the question do I say that I'm leaving the SSH session. The CORRECT answer is, that you don't have to do anything special. I just had a typo in my clients IP address.

Comment: @NativeCoder Yeah I saw it in the edit review queue. Unfortunately, I am just slightly below 2000 rep. so I couldn't approve the edit!